# How to create a shell script to copy the given files to a particular folder?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

1. I have abc1.txt ,abc2.txt,abc3.txt,abc4.txt....abc42.txt files in folder1.
2. I have abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4.....abc42 folders .

Problem is 
3. I want to write a script which adds abc1.txt to abc1 folder ,abc2.txt to abc2 folder ,abc3.txt to abc3 folder and so on for all the files .

Please help me on this ?

Comment: all files and folders are in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in abc*.txt; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done
```

Comment: What is the use of shopt -s nullglob?

Comment: So that script doesn't run when there is no `abc*.txt` file.